# Draw a soccer pitch in android

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

i need to draw a soccer pitch in my application.

In the soccer pitch i need to write player name deployed through training.

Example:

Training: 4-4-2

```
                            GOALKEEPER
      PLAYER1        PLAYER2       PLAYER3       PLAYER4

      PLAYER5        PLAYER6       PLAYER7       PLAYER8

                    PLAYER9        PLAYER10
```

OR:

Training: 4-3-2-1

```
                            GOALKEEPER
      PLAYER1        PLAYER2       PLAYER3       PLAYER4

                PLAYER5        PLAYER6       PLAYER7

                    PLAYER8        PLAYER9

                             PLAYER10
```

I know that i can use `surfaceview` or `canvas` but i don't know how.

Can someone give me right advise?

Thanks!

Comment: Ask to draw a football field and see if you get any answers.

Comment: I don't know if you are still looking for this, but I made this. If you are interested I could send you the code.

Comment: Hi, yes, i'm still interested. Could you please send me the code?

Comment: ey! Tim, have you share your code anywhere?

Comment: @tim: Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing. Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Hi, if you still need to draw a soccer pitch, you can find [here](https://github.com/brkckr/FirstEleven)